# Override Category Layout

Tags: category, magento-enterprise, layout, catalog, enterprise-1.14

I require some assistance on Magento 1.14. I am currently coding a new theme for a an existing Magento website and require the Catalog layouts all to be 1 column as opposed to the default "2 Columns With Left".

When I change the "page layout" under one of the categories it changes on the front-end as you would expect. However I don't want to have to go through each category and set these to 1 column.

I have tried an override in local.xml file but this doesn't seem to affect anything, please could someone advise. This is the code I added to the local.xml file

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

Regards

Comment: did you clear a cache?

Comment: Yep! All caching is disabled and also to double check I removed the files manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML is correct, I have exactly the same and it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

#### What you should check now:

- Clear the Magento cache
- Is the `local.xml` actually used? It should be in the `layout` directory of the currently configured theme. A quick and easy way to find out if the file is used, is to add some invalid XML like `<<<` at the end and see if the site breaks.
- Are the categories explicitly set up to use the Two Column layout? It should look like this ("No layout updates"):

  [image: Screenshot of category configuration]

---

What you should also know is that the there are two different layout handles for anchor categories (i.e. with layered navigation) and non-anchor categories, so that you can apply updates to only one of these instead to `catalog_category_view`:

- `catalog_category_default`
- `catalog_category_layered`

Comment: Is it possible that this could have been overwritten elsewhere? The local.xml file is definitely being used, I did have some errors in a template but even now these have been cleaned up the template still doesn't change.

Comment: Since `local.xml` is always the last layout file that gets merged, it could only be overridden in the same file, in the settings for each category itself or somewhere in custom code.

Comment: Sorry, you mention, "in the settings for each category itself" would you be referring to this setting: [here](http://screencast.com/t/spr8CAfIls)

Comment: Yes. This should be "no changes", otherwise it takes precedence over anything from the layout XML

Comment: I see, and theres no way to 'globally override' this setting?

Comment: What you can do is to reset the erroneously set "Page Layout" attribute, using plain SQL: `DELETE FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id=61` (**Warning:** make a backup, and verify what you are deleting first with `SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id=61`). Then your global setting from `local.xml` will take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you 100% sure that your `local.xml` is used? Then try to also set the template for the more specific layout handles `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered`:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```